# How can I change screens after 3 seconds of entering the screen?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to switch screens to screen 2 from screen 1 after 3 seconds of being on screen 1.

The program compiles but it just stays on Screen1 and I want it to change to screen2 after 3 seconds of being on screen1.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Screen1(Screen):
    def callNext(self, dt):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen1()
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**kv file:**

```
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
<Screen1>:
    name: 'screen1'
    on_enter:
        Clock.schedule_once(self.callNext, 3)
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'logokivy.png'

<Screen2>:
    name: 'screen2'
    Button:
        text: 'Hello'
```

Comment: Your `build()` method has two returns. Is that intentional?

Comment: no actually haha thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't use a ScreenManager. Make the root widget a ScreenManager with the two screens as children, and it looks like everything else should be fine and it will work.

Comment: it doesnt work when it is on_enter but it works when it is on_parent but i need it to be on_enter

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `import time` and use `time.sleep()` to wait 3 seconds and then close it.